# Request to Enable MathJax/LaTeX Rendering on Philosophy Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, math

I am ready to formally propose we enable this on this site to whoever has the power to enable it. I actually could not find information about that with a little Googling. Can a moderator please forward this information to the responsible parties? Thanks very much.

Comment: This has been declined several times already since the original request. Short answer: No, we will not get it.